# Ubuntu is not able to boot after the installation of graphic driver amdgpu-pro

Tags: boot, 18.04, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I installed amdgpu-pro graphic driver from this site https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-635
After restarting it was unable to boot, It was showing the ubuntu loading screen, I couldn’t type anything and nothing else could be done except turning off the device by holding the power button.
I tried many ways but nothing worked out.
I tried all possible solutions from this blog https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/
After adding the command nomodeset, this screen appeared with error message hdaudio hdaudioCOD2:unable to bind codec [error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjHWO.jpg) and stuck here.I cannot do a fresh install as 4 years worth of work will be gone. How do I fix this?

My ubuntu version is 18.04, kernel 5.4.58, laptop model HP 15-ay007tx and hardware details:- https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c05138543

Comment: I do not see your AMD chip on the list of supported products. https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-10 So you should not install AMD-pro version. Can you boot recovery mode to a terminal & uninstall it? Otherwise you may need to either chroot to see if you can repair it, or reinstall & restore your data from your backups. Rule pretty much is your data is not valuable unless you do back it up as drives fail, systems fail and users make mistakes. And then data is gone.

Comment: If you are still able to boot to the grub menu, press e and add nomodeset at the end of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= then report back. If this gets you in you might find it easier to remove/replace the promlematic driver.

Comment: I fixed it! Thank you so much for your help. I somehow accessed the terminal by tinkering around and then did as you said oldfred, uninstalled it and now its working. Only one question. Which graphics driver should i use then? Ruling out AMDGPU-PRO, should I rather use AMDGPU or Oibaf's drivers?